# Netbeans "application/x-javascript" tags

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans

I am using Netbeans to edit my HTML project.
I have defined the project as a PHP project (although it is just HTML).

The problem: Netbeans does not recognize this as Javascript:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
```

or

```
<script type="application/x-javascript">
```

As such it does not enable Javascript editing features. (Autocomplete and such...)

Instead it only recognizes `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Is there a custom way to cause the editor to recognize `"application/javascript"` as Javascript?

Comment: what is the version of netbeans that you are using?

Comment: I suppose you could mark everything up as "text/javascript" and then do a project-wide find-n-replace when you deploy.  Though, this isn't a sustainable solution.

Comment: - I am using nightly build 7.02 and also version 6.9 .

Answer (score 1):

I believe Netbeans is looking for `<script type="text/javascript">` before autocomplete is enabled. They are probably following the W3 HTML specification for inline [JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2.2).

The question on which is the correct MIME type for JavaScript comes up often. The official MIME type is application/javascript, but some browsers don't support this. The industry standard has become 'text/javascript'.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the javascript in a separate file from the HTML would solve it, wouldn't it? Or is that not an option?

Found this: http://forums.netbeans.org/topic6181.html

Comment: No,The problem is this project is allready 90% done. I have gotten into it now... I do not want to change the current HTML files (that would be impolite...).

Comment: ok, you can be polite and suffer, or you can make the script tags src to the js files and have context editing :^) your choice.